# How to setup dynamic 'Read More' button in a long text in VueJs in array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have been learning Vue JS not too long ago

And I have some problems with solving certain problems

In this situation, I need to make an event that will hide and show long text in a specific object

The logic of my application is as follows

I am sending a request to the server

I get an answer

Then I write it to the Vuex store

And using a getter and loop for output in the component

If someone has encountered a similar situation, I will be grateful for any help.

This is part of my code

```
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";


<v-list three-line v-for="(comment, index) in product.comments.data" :key="comment.id" class="mb-3">

    <v-list-item>
       <p v-if="!readMoreActivated">{{comment.description.slice(0, 200)}}<v-btn @click="activateReadMore(index, comment.description)" x-small text color="grey">Открыть</v-btn></p>
       <p v-if="readMoreActivated">{{comment.description}}</p>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>



computed: {
        ...mapGetters("products", ["product"])

    },

methods: {
        activateReadMore(lineId, comment)
        {
            comment.findIndex((lineId) => {
                return comment.slice(1, comment.length)
            })
            // this.readMoreActivated = true
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

You really don’t even need methods for this one! Take a look at this component code for it, and I’ll also link to a working Codepen for it.

One of the greatest things about Vue is how little code you actually have to write, once you wrap your head around state management, rather than manually driving events.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      {{ formattedBody }}
      <button @click="showingFullText = !showingFullText">
        Read {{ showingFullText ? "Less" : "More" }}
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showingFullText: false,
      body:
        "I am some text! Instead of being on the data object, though, I would be pulled from the store."
    };
  },

  computed: {
    formattedBody() {
      if (this.showingFullText) {
        return this.body;
      }

      return `${this.body.slice(0, 20).trim()}...`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/barneychampaign/pen/KKMOZqL

Comment: Thanks for the help, but either I am doing something wrong or this is not the solution that I need
For more understanding, I edited my code

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```js
Vue.component('ListItem', {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showFullText: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    displayedText() {
      if (!this.showFullText) {
        return this.text.slice(0, 200)
      } else {
        return this.text
      }
    },
    readMoreText() {
      return this.showFullText ? 'less' : 'more'
    }
  },
  template: `
    <li>
      <div>
        {{ displayedText }}
      </div>
      <button
        @click="showFullText = !showFullText"
      >
        Read {{ readMoreText }}...
      </button>
    </li>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      textArray: [
        '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sollicitudin nunc sed finibus porttitor. Praesent elementum lacinia ullamcorper. Donec at pretium nisi, at mollis ante. Morbi maximus, sapien a mattis scelerisque, orci dui viverra turpis, at ultricies risus lectus sed justo. Donec venenatis ullamcorper odio, rutrum auctor leo vehicula ut.',
        '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sollicitudin nunc sed finibus porttitor. Praesent elementum lacinia ullamcorper. Donec at pretium nisi, at mollis ante. Morbi maximus, sapien a mattis scelerisque, orci dui viverra turpis, at ultricies risus lectus sed justo. Donec venenatis ullamcorper odio, rutrum auctor leo vehicula ut.',
        '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sollicitudin nunc sed finibus porttitor. Praesent elementum lacinia ullamcorper. Donec at pretium nisi, at mollis ante. Morbi maximus, sapien a mattis scelerisque, orci dui viverra turpis, at ultricies risus lectus sed justo. Donec venenatis ullamcorper odio, rutrum auctor leo vehicula ut.'
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <list-item v-for="(text, i) in textArray" :key="i" :text="text" />
  </ol>
</div>
```

The main point is:

- a `component` is created for the list entries. The read less & read more action is "confined" to this component only
- the text is a `prop` for each `ListItem`